# How do I change the address used by a CXF Web Service to one different than the one specified in the wsdl file?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I've got it working when I get the wsdl based on configuration, but I'd like to just tell it to use a specific address for the service call and use a local copy of the wsdl.

```
MyWebService serviceDefinition = new MyWebService(new URL(wsdlLocation));
service = serviceDefinition.getMyWebServicePort();
```

Does anyone know the best practice for this?

xml request that works.

```
<soap:Body>
<ns2:getData xmlns:ns2="http://services.test.com/">
<arg0>Test Name</arg0>
<arg1>55555555</arg1>
</ns2:getData>
</soap:Body>
```

proxy xml request that doesn't work.

```
<soap:Body>
<ns1:getData xmlns:ns1="http://ws.test.com/">
<ns3:arg0 xmlns:ns2="http://services.test.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.test.com/">Test Name</ns3:arg0>
<ns3:arg1 xmlns:ns2="http://services.test.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.test.com/">55555555</ns3:arg1>
</ns1:getData>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: I'm also using ws-security, so I'm not sure if that complicates this or not...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you use the [ClientProxyFactoryBean](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/simple-frontend.html)?  You don't even need the WSDL if you have the compiled stubs.  For example:

```
ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/Hello");
HelloWorld client = (HelloWorld) factory.create();
```

Comment: This worked in that it makes the web service call, but the arguments it passes cannot be read by the remote web service. The values are null when it gets to my method on the server side. The arguments are being sent (checked the xml being sent in the request).

Comment: It was working 100% using the remote wsdl, not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: What is the difference between the XML when using this method and the remote wsdl method?

Comment: I updated my question with the xml sent by each method of requesting the web service. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: You probably need the JAX-WS subclass of ClientProxyFactoryBean:  JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.   The basic ClientProxyFactoryBean woudln't know about the jaxws annotations and such that would probably be required in this case.

Answer (score 6):

```
MyWebService serviceDefinition = new MyWebService(new URL(wsdlLocation));
service = serviceDefinition.getMyWebServicePort();

((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext()
    .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://localhost:8080/foobar");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanfactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/Hello");
HelloWorld client = (HelloWorld) factory.create();
```

**JaxWS** instead of **Client** infront of FactoryBeanfactory worked for us.