# CXF client loads wsdl for both service and port?

Tags: wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

In a java web app, I need to call a remote soap service, and I'm trying to use a CXF 2.5.0-generated client.  The soap service is provided by a particular ERP vendor, and its wsdl is monstrous, thousands of types, dozens of xsd imports, etc.  wsdl2java generates the client ok, thanks to the -autoNameResolution flag.  But at runtime it retrieves the remote wsdl twice, once when I create the service object, and again when I create a port object.

```
MyService_Service myService = new MyService_Service(giantWsdlUrl);  // fetches giantWsdl
MyService myPort = myService.getMyServicePort();  // fetches giantWsdl again
```

Why is that?  I can understand retrieving it when creating myService, you want to see that it matches the client I'm currently using, or let a runtime wsdl location dictate the endpoint address, etc.  But I don't understand why asking for the port would reload everything it *just* went out on the wire for.  Am I missing something?

Since this is in a web application, and I [can't be sure that myPort is threadsafe](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%3F), then I'd have to create a port for each thread, except that's way too slow, 6 to 8 seconds thanks to the monstrous wsdl.  Or add my own pooling, create a bunch in advance, and do check-outs and check-ins.  Yuck.

For the record, the [JaxWsProxyFactoryBean creation route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422037/545195) does *not* ever fetch the wsdl, and that's good for my situation.  It still takes a long time on the first create(), then about a quarter second on subsequent create()s, and even that's less than desirable.  And I dunno... it sorta feels like I'm under the hood hotwiring the thing rather than turning the key.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have actually answered the question yourself. Each time you invoke `service.getPort()` the WSDL is loaded from remote site and parsed. [`JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.1.0/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java#JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.FeaturePortProvider.getPortStub%28javax.xml.ws.Service%2Cjavax.xml.namespace.QName%2Cjava.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) goes absolutely the same way, but once the proxy is obtained it is re-used for further invocations. That is why the 1st run is slow (because of "warming up"), but subsequent are fast.

And yes, `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` is not thread-safe. Pooling client proxies is an option, but unfortunately will eat a lot of memory, as [JAX-WS runtime model is not shared among client proxies](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-942); synchronization is perhaps better way to follow.

Comment: What I was hoping to understand is *why* it fetches the wsdl every time a service object is created *and* every time a port object is created.  If it's a bug, if it's something I'm not doing right, etc.  It throws a real monkeywrench into my design.  And using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean never fetches the remote wsdl, I don't pass it one, and it never requests the default.  All I give it is an endpoint address.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps the way you create your service is not optimal. Try the following code: `MySEI sei = Service.getPort(MySEI.class);`.